# Exiting a loop without break statement?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

For homework I need to prompt the user to enter words until they either enter 20 words or type the word 'done'. Right now I have a function with a while loop that scans in each word entered but the loop doesn't end when the user types 'done'.

function:

```
int wordentry(int row, int col, char a[20][100])

{

int i = 0;/* Counter */


    printf("Enter 20 words you would like hidden in the puzzle, or type 'done' when finished:\n");

    /* While the user hasn't entered 20 words, or the user hasn't entered the word 'done' the prompt to enter words keeps looping */

    while(i < 20)
    {
      scanf("%c",a[i]);
      if(strcmp(a[i],"done") == 0)
      {
        return(i);
      }
      i++;

    }/* Ends while loop */



return(i);

}/* Ends function */
```

The variable `row` is a user determined variable that is the row length of a word search puzzle that each word is getting inserted into and the variable `col` is the user determined length of each column. The array `a` is where each word is getting stored as a string. The return variable `i` is meant to keep track of the number of words that the user entered. Also, unless there's a `switch` statement, I can't use any `break` statements. I'm getting frustrated because I can't figure out how to do this right. Can someone please help?

Comment: Suggest `if (scanf("%99s",a[i]) != 1) Handle_Error_Somehow();`

Answer (score 3):

The scanf is only reading a single character which is what `%c` indicates.  So the comparison is comparing 'd' to "done" which will not be equal.  Use `%s` so you get the entire word entered and then continue debugging your problem.

```
  scanf("%s",a[i]);

  if(strcmp(a[i],"done") == 0)
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the strcmp in the if statement is returning always false. I don't have a good experience with C programming language, But try to put something like this

```
...
scanf("%s",&a[0]);
if(strcmp(a[i],"done") == 0)
...
```

(don't forget to include string.h)

Answer (score 0):

To get out of a loop without a `break` statement, you need to satisfy the condition that keeps the loop running. So when you have the following:

```
while (i < 20)
```

Setting `i` to 20 or greater will keep the loop from executing again. The one difference being it will continue to the end of the current run instead of exiting immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid redundancy and hard-coded values, any condition that changes your control flow is worth making explicit so avoid goto, continue, and break (other than in switch statements) and characters are cheap so give your variables some meaningful names:

```
#define MAXWORDS 20
#define MAXCHARS 99

int wordEntry(int row, int col, char words[MAXWORDS][MAXCHARS+1])
{

    int numEntered = 0;
    int userDone = 0;
    char *doneWord = "done";

    printf("Enter %d words you would like hidden in the puzzle, or type '%s' when finished:\n", MAXWORDS, doneWord);

    /* While the user hasn't entered max words, or the user hasn't entered the word 'done' the prompt to enter words keeps looping */

    while( !userDone && (numEntered < MAXWORDS) )
    {
        scanf("%s",words[numEntered]);
        if (strcmp(words[numEntered],doneWord) == 0)
        {
            userDone = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            numEntered++;
        }

    }/* Ends while loop */

    return numEntered;

}/* Ends function */
```

Also read http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html before deciding to use scanf().

Comment: Good improvements! Nit: `doneWord` could be `char const * const`.